# Strategies for OA rejections on CIP when same claims allowed by different examiner for a preceding CON

Tags: examiner, rejection, oa

I have a first OA on a CIP wherein the examiner has rejected claims identical to ones allowed in a related CON (actually granted now), which had a different examiner. (The rejections are not stated to be double-patenting issues.) Should I point out the prior allowance, or should I ignore it and just do the best I can to answer to the rejections?

Comment: Of course if they are truly identical the claim in the CIP should never issue due to statutory double patenting.   That seems to make the question moot.

Comment: Further clarifying: The CIP includes claims identical to those of an issued CON, but also adds new and modified claims. A Terminal Disclaimer is filed. So why would the question be moot? Does the examiner have authority to disagree with the earlier examiner, even when the currently cited prior art's date precedes that earlier examination?

Comment: Two patents can not issue with identical claims. There are two kinds of double patenting. Terminal disclaimer lets you have new claims that would be obvious in light of the subject mater of the claims in the earlier. It does NOT let you have identical claims.

Comment: I just had a discussion with the patent examiner assigned to my application. He says the CIP application CAN include claims that are identical to those of a previously issued patent in the same family, as well as (presumably, one would of course include) the new claims covering the material added to specs.

Comment: I hope this is a misunderstanding on you part. A CIP can contain claims that are only supported by the patent application and also claims that are dependent on the aided subject mater of the CIP. Statutory double patenting involves getting more than one patent to the same exact thing. A terminal disclaimer can't fix that.

Comment: I don' think it could be a misunderstanding. I stated it in several different ways to the examiner, to make sure we were talking about the same thing. The application is a duplicate of the previous CON, but with material added to specs, including new drawings. The claims are a duplicate from the CON, but with new claims added. He agreed, it is not the same exact thing. As he further explained, the new material can't claim the same priority date as the older material that's being carried forward.

Comment: " He agreed that it is not the same thing" does not compute with "claims are a duplicate from the CON".

Comment: True – But *only* if one pays no attention to the statement (mentioned twice, previously) that the CIP also includes both new and modified claims – thus making it, by definition, non-identical.

Comment: are they duplicate claims or modified claims ? Modified is ok, duplicate  is not

Comment: Modified, plus some with exactly same wording. But if the latter are dependent upon newly modified independents, then they are no longer duplicates of previously used ones, correct?

Comment: In that case the claim is not the same.